# arc4random_uniform 64-bit ios

Tags: ios, 64-bit

What is the best way to use arc4random_uniform in a device independent (32-bit/64-bit) manner?  I have the following line:

```
UIColor *itemColor = [colors objectAtIndex: (arc4random_uniform([colors count]))];
```

On 64-bit you get a loss of precision when converting [colors count] to the argument for arc4random_uniform.  On 32-bit it is fine.

What I'm trying to do is to rewrite this line so it doesn't throw a warning when compiled under either 32-bit or 64-bit.  It is safe to assume [colors count] will not assume a value greater than 16.  Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: Add an explicit cast to `uint32_t`? I doubt your array has more than 4 billion elements...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add an explicit cast to `uint32_t`

```
UIColor *itemColor = [colors objectAtIndex:(arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[colors count]))];
```

this removes the warning, and it does NOT result in a loss of precision, when converting this 64-bit value to a 32-bit value. never ever. because the number of elements in an array can never exceed 2^32 on an iPhone. 2^32 items on an array would require at least 32GB just to store the pointers... and I don't talk about the objects being pointed to.